# About action menu(overflow) with actionbarsherlock 4.0 RC

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I've got how to add overflow action menu with actionbarsherlock 4.0 RC on the ActionBar.But I can not change the background color for each menu item in the drop-down popup when I click the action menu button on the top-right of the actionbar.
How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add / the properties
**android:popupMenuStyle** & **android:dropDownListViewStyle**
to your theme. They need to point to two styles where you can customize the overflow.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <!-- Action bar styles -->
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/NTCPopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/NTCDropDownListView</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/NTCPopupMenu</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/NTCDropDownListView</item>
</style>
```

and the styles

```
<!-- overflow menu -->
<style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/background</item>
</style>

<!-- style the items within the overflow menu -->
<style name="MyDropDownListView" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/divider</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/item_background</item>
</style>
```

There is one thing in this example that differs from the example on the ActionBarSherlock website and that is that my theme has a different parent. see different post here:
[ActionbarSherlock overflow menu styling issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138767/actionbarsherlock-overflow-menu-styling-issue)