# ActionbarSherlock overflow menu styling issue

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am following the examples on the ActionbarSherlock website

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/bg_striped</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_striped</item>

    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/bg_striped_split</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/bg_striped_split</item>
</style>
```

however with this setup I am not able to change the style for the overflow menu. 
the properties "**android:popupMenuStyle**" and "**android:dropDownListViewStyle**" is completely ignored.

If i change the themes parent to "**Theme.Sherlock.Light**" it works. Is this intentional? If not how would you style the overflow menu dropdown and at the same time keep the themes parent "**Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar**" as per the example on the Sherlock website.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should check out this actionbar style generator. It works great and should help resolve your issue: http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/